# How to get rid of newlines in XML sent via POST-request

Tags: python, xml, http, python-requests

I'm trying to send `.xml` file via `POST` request:

```
files = {"FileName": open (path_to_file.xml, "rb")}
requests.post(url, files=files)
```

But file that sent from client side as

```
  <protection>
     <create name="domain1/domain2/>
     <allowed name="domain1"/>
     <allowed name="domain2"/>
  </protection>
```

Received on server side as

```
  <protection>

     <create name="domain1/domain2/>

     <allowed name="domain1"/>

     <allowed name="domain2"/>

  </protection>
```

Did someone faced with such issue?

Comment: Why do you use `"rb"` as the read mode? Why not `r`?

Comment: Your question is interesting and I'm just curious. Since spaces does not have an influence on XML, why do you carry about it?

Comment: My opinion is that, HTTP request header will end with two \r\n, after which the POST data comes. This will cause the POST data to start with the \r\n of your actual header end marker. Try adding an strip() / rstrip() to your header.

Comment: @Naga2Raja There is no truncation of two characters. Nothing is missing, to many bytes are read on the server.

Comment: @rsm , I get error from server while it tries to parse file

Comment: @LutzHorn, Yeap! Seem that this cause the issue. Using `"r"` solve the problem